# Determine if an element has a CSS class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working with jQuery and looking to see if there is an easy way to determine if the element has a specific CSS class associated with it.

I have the id of the element, and the CSS class that I'm looking for.  I just need to be able to, in an if statement, do a comparison based on the existence of that class on the element.

Comment: If you want to do it without jQuery, [“hasClass” with javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5085567/1529630)

Answer (score 238, accepted):

Use the `hasClass` method:

```
jQueryCollection.hasClass(className);
```

or

```
$(selector).hasClass(className);
```

The argument is (obviously) a string representing the class you are checking, and it returns a boolean (so it doesn't support chaining like most jQuery methods).

**Note:** If you pass a `className` argument that contains whitespace, it will be matched literally against the collection's elements' `className` string. So if, for instance, you have an element,

```
<span class="foo bar" />
```

then this will return `true`:

```
$('span').hasClass('foo bar')
```

and these will return `false`:

```
$('span').hasClass('bar foo')
$('span').hasClass('foo  bar')
```

Comment: I disagree. The documentation's organized under categories, but you can easily see all the methods alphabetically as well. Everything comes with an example, and the comments section usually clears up anything that's left out. jQuery has a LOT of excellent functions and utilities and it takes some learning to discover them all.
-EDIT- That makes sense, it's definitely come a long way.

Comment: @Trafalmadorian, I've removed my original comment because the situation has changed. Originally you had posted everything before -EDIT-, and I replied that my comment about the documentation quality was no longer relevant but referred to their previous (MediaWiki) system. You then deleted your previous comment and reposed with the -EDIT-. I hope that this cleanup is a little clearer and less misleading to future readers.

Comment: @daniloquio, it is if you go directly to api.jquery.com ... for some reason the website still links to the awful wiki version at docs.jquery.com

Answer (score 21):

from the [FAQ](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_test_whether_an_element_has_a_particular_class.3F)

```
elem = $("#elemid");
if (elem.is (".class")) {
   // whatever
}
```

or:

```
elem = $("#elemid");
if (elem.hasClass ("class")) {
   // whatever
}
```

Comment: careful with .is() - "The is() method in jQuery will return true if ANY of the elements in the current collection match ANY of the elements in the is-based collection" - http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1725-jQuery-s-is-Method-Checks-For-Any-Matching-Elements.htm

Answer (score 11):

As for the negation, if you want to know if an element hasn't a class you can simply do as Mark said.

```
if (!currentPage.parent().hasClass('home')) { do what you want }
```

Answer (score 3):

Without jQuery:

```
var hasclass=!!(' '+elem.className+' ').indexOf(' check_class ')+1;
```

Or:

```
function hasClass(e,c){
    return e&&(e instanceof HTMLElement)&&!!((' '+e.className+' ').indexOf(' '+c+' ')+1);
}
/*example of usage*/
var has_class_medium=hasClass(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0],'medium');
```

This is WAY faster than jQuery!

Comment: why do you do `...&&!!((' '+e.classname+' ').indexOf(' '+c+' ')+1)`, and not just `&&!(' '+e.classname+' ').indexOf(' '+c+' ')`?

Comment: Because `indexOf` returns `-1` is the class doesn't exist. If I do `!!-1`, it would be `true`. Since I'm doing `!!-1+1`, it will be false. A better way would be `...&&!!~(' '+e.className+' ').indexOf(' '+c+' ')`, but I didn't remembered it at the time.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `...&&~(' '+e.className+' ').indexOf(' '+c+' ')`

Answer (score 3):

In the interests of helping anyone who lands here but was actually looking for a jQuery free way of doing this:

```
element.classList.contains('your-class-name')
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the official jQuery FAQ page :

[How do I test whether an element has perticular class or not](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-test-whether-an-element-has-a-particular-class/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.segment-name').click(function () {
    if($(this).hasClass('segment-a')){
        //class exist
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case , I used the 'is' a jQuery function, I had a HTML element with different css classes added , I was looking for a specific class in the middle of these , so I used the "is" a good alternative to check a class dynamically added to an html element , which already has other css classes, it is another good alternative.

**simple example :**

```
 <!--element html-->
 <nav class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-horizontal cbp-spmenu-bottom cbp-spmenu-open" id="menu">somethings here... </nav>

 <!--jQuery "is"-->
 $('#menu').is('.cbp-spmenu-open');
```

**advanced example :**

```
 <!--element html-->
    <nav class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-horizontal cbp-spmenu-bottom cbp-spmenu-open" id="menu">somethings here... </nav>

   <!--jQuery "is"-->
    if($('#menu').is('.cbp-spmenu-bottom.cbp-spmenu-open')){
       $("#menu").show();
    }
```