# What is the "hasClass" function with plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

How do you do jQuery’s `hasClass` with plain ol’ JavaScript? For example,

```html
<body class="foo thatClass bar">
```

What’s the JavaScript way to ask if `<body>` has `thatClass`?

Comment: I suppose you would have to parse the `class` property (which in case of multiple classes will have multiple class names in random order separated by a space) and check whether your class name is in it. Not terribly difficult, but still terribly inconvenient if not for learning purposes :)

Comment: don't know if I'm late for the party but a good site that gives alternatives to jQuery functions is http://youmightnotneedjquery.com

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You can check whether `element.className` matches `/\bthatClass\b/`.
`\b` matches a word break.

Or, you can use jQuery's own implementation:

```
var className = " " + selector + " ";
if ( (" " + element.className + " ").replace(/[\n\t]/g, " ").indexOf(" thatClass ") > -1 )
```

To answer your more general question, you can look at jQuery's [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery) on github or at the source for [`hasClass` specifically in this source viewer](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.5.0&fn=jQuery.fn.hasClass).

Comment: +1 for jQuery implementation (of for having looked up (is this proper English?) what `rclass` actually is ;))

Comment: Wouldn't `\b` match "thatClass-anotherClass"?

Comment: just for completeness: rclass in recent versions is "/[\n\t\r]/g" (\r added)

Comment: @FelixSchwarz is right, in current jQuery the regexp was updated to `/[\t\r\n\f]/g`. Also it's good to mention that `/\bclass\b/` can fail for classnames with `-` minus sign (other than that it works good) , that's why jQuery's implementation is better and more reliable. For example: `/\bbig\b/.test('big-text')` returns true instead of expected false.

Comment: How did this discussion turn into jQuery when the original question was asking for a non-jQuery implementation?

Comment: what is selector here?

Comment: @DavidManess - often times a "non-jquery" solution involves grabbing the guts of a jquery function so that you don't have to pull in the whole library. This is important because jquery has been battle-tested by millions of users and developers across every imaginable browser.

Answer (score 1477):

**Simply use `classList.contains()`:**

```
if (document.body.classList.contains('thatClass')) {
    // do some stuff
}
```

**Other uses of `classList`:**

```
document.body.classList.add('thisClass');
// $('body').addClass('thisClass');

document.body.classList.remove('thatClass');
// $('body').removeClass('thatClass');

document.body.classList.toggle('anotherClass');
// $('body').toggleClass('anotherClass');
```

**Browser Support:**

- Chrome 8.0
- Firefox 3.6
- IE 10
- Opera 11.50
- Safari 5.1

[`classList` Browser Support](http://caniuse.com/#search=classList)

Comment: **This is unsupported in IE8**. IE8 can retrieve `.classList` as a string, but it will not recognise the more modern methods such as `.classList.contains()`

Comment: @iono In the [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) implementation description from the MDN there is a shim that extend the support to this behavior to IE8 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: I agree with @AlexanderWigmore, this was incredibly helpful and simple.

Comment: This should be the acceptable answer since 2020. As no one talk about IE8 / WinXP anymore.

Comment: Agree. .. IE8 is dead. IE in general is dead. This should be the way moving forward.

Answer (score 36):

The most effective one liner that

- returns a boolean (as opposed to Orbling's answer)
- Does not return a false positive when searching for `thisClass` on an element that has `class="thisClass-suffix"`.
- is compatible with every browser down to at least IE6

---

```
function hasClass( target, className ) {
    return new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)').test(target.className);
}
```

Answer (score 33):

```js
// 1. Use if for see that classes:

if (document.querySelector(".section-name").classList.contains("section-filter")) {
  alert("Grid section");
  // code...
}
```

```html
<!--2. Add a class in the .html:-->

<div class="section-name section-filter">...</div>
```

Comment: @greg_diesel: do not discourage answers! New solutions for common problems are more than welcome.

Comment: @Raveren while new solutions to old problems are welcomed, this particular answer brings nothing new. It only adds noise to this question.

Comment: @raveren This isn't a new solution, it's the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16337545/1863564) but with less information.

Comment: new solution = not noise... this new solution = perfect answer for me... this is why "do not discourage new solutions" comment was made...

Answer (score 32):

The attribute that stores the classes in use is `className`.

So you can say:

```
if (document.body.className.match(/\bmyclass\b/)) {
    ....
}
```

If you want a location that shows you how jQuery does everything, I would suggest:

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js

Comment: Excellent. The `match` attribute comes handy again! Does really jQuery does something more than is possible in JavaScript?! If not, jQuery is just an unnecessary weight of shorthands.

Comment: This also matches `myclass-something`, as `\b` matches hyphen.

Comment: @animaacija All javascript libraries/plugins are basically javascript shorthands because they are build with javascript. Thing is: Shorthands are always necessary. Never reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I think classList.contains('className') is a better solution than this. Avoid the generalizations Edwin. You should stop using so much words such as "always" and "never"

Answer (score 22):

#### Element.matches()

Instead of `$(element).hasClass('example')` in jQuery, you can use `element.matches('.example')` in plain JavaScript:

```
if (element.matches('.example')) {
  // Element has example class ...
}
```

[View Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: hasClass drop-in w/ es6...

`hasClass = (el, name) => el.matches('.'+name) ? 1 : 0`

Comment: should be the top answer.

Comment: Indeed shortest, but probably slower (https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/7742/0/matches-vs-closest-vs-classlist).

Answer (score 13):

hasClass function:

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.hasClass = function(cls) {
    var i;
    var classes = this.className.split(" ");
    for(i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
        if(classes[i] == cls) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

addClass function:

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.addClass = function(add) {
    if (!this.hasClass(add)){
        this.className = (this.className + " " + add).trim();
    }
};
```

removeClass function:

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.removeClass = function(remove) {
    var newClassName = "";
    var i;
    var classes = this.className.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ').split(" ");
    for(i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
        if(classes[i] !== remove) {
            newClassName += classes[i] + " ";
        }
    }
    this.className = newClassName.trim();
};
```

Answer (score 11):

I use a simple/minimal solution, one line, cross browser, and works with legacy browsers as well:

```
/\bmyClass/.test(document.body.className) // notice the \b command for whole word 'myClass'
```

This method is great because does not require [polyfills](http://polyfill.io) and if you use them for `classList` it's much better in terms of performance. At least for me.

Update: I made a tiny polyfill that's an all round solution I use now:

```
function hasClass(element,testClass){
  if ('classList' in element) { return element.classList.contains(testClass);
} else { return new Regexp(testClass).exec(element.className); } // this is better

//} else { return el.className.indexOf(testClass) != -1; } // this is faster but requires indexOf() polyfill
  return false;
}
```

For the other class manipulation, see the complete file [here](https://github.com/thednp/minifill/blob/master/classList.js).

Comment: Will this trip over a class of `notmyClassHere`?

Comment: You can also ask if your class isn't there as well `!/myClass/.test(document.body.className)` notice the `!` symbol.

Comment: I'm not talking about negating the question.  I'm thinking that your function will improperly return true if the class name is `thisIsmyClassHere`.

Comment: I was only guessing that's what you ask about, didn't understand exactly what you need, but have you tried it and it failed returning true/false as it should?

Comment: This is not perfect as it is not substrings proof. E.g. when document.body.className = 'myClass123', then /myClass/.test(document.body.className) return true...

Comment: In that case you can do some more regex to also handle substrings, in most cases this is so helpful. At least for me.

Comment: @ZbigniewWiadro I updated the answer to only check words, `/\bmyClass123/` will test exactly that.

Answer (score 9):

a good solution for this is to work with classList and contains.

i did it like this:

```
... for ( var i = 0; i < container.length; i++ ) {
        if ( container[i].classList.contains('half_width') ) { ...
```

So you need your element and check the list of the classes. If one of the classes is the same as the one you search for it will return true if not it will return false!

Answer (score 9):

This 'hasClass' function works in IE8+, FireFox and Chrome:

```
hasClass = function(el, cls) {
    var regexp = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + cls + '(\\s|$)'),
        target = (typeof el.className === 'undefined') ? window.event.srcElement : el;
    return target.className.match(regexp);
}
```

[Updated Jan'2021] A better way:

```
hasClass = (el, cls) => {
  [...el.classList].includes(cls); //cls without dot
};
```

Comment: Better:   [...el.classList].includes(cls);  //cls without dot

Comment: I think you meant `[...el.classList].contains(cls);` for the 2021 update, right?

Comment: Node.contains is used for childnodes. With [...  ] it converts the DOMTokenList into an Array of the node's classes. To search into an array I use includes

Answer (score 6):

Use something like:

```
Array.prototype.indexOf.call(myHTMLSelector.classList, 'the-class');
```

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to `myHTMLSelector.classList.indexOf('the-class')`?  Don't you also want `>=0` at the end?

Comment: What's the point of using `[].indexOf` if `classList` has a `contains` method?

Comment: @Teepeemm no. `myHTMLSelector.classList.indexOf('the-class')` returns the error that `myHTMLSelector.classList.indexOf is not a function` because `myHTMLSelector.classList` is not an array. But I guess when calling it using `Array.prototype` some conversion happens. This may support older browser, though `contains` has very good support.

Answer (score 6):

```
if (document.body.className.split(/\s+/).indexOf("thatClass") !== -1) {
    // has "thatClass"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well all of the above answers are pretty good but here is a small simple function I whipped up. It works pretty well.

```
function hasClass(el, cn){
    var classes = el.classList;
    for(var j = 0; j < classes.length; j++){
        if(classes[j] == cn){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of iterating if `classList` has a `contains` method?

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about this approach?

```
<body class="thatClass anotherClass"> </body>

var bodyClasses = document.querySelector('body').className;
var myClass = new RegExp("thatClass");
var trueOrFalse = myClass.test( bodyClasses );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5sv30bhe/

Comment: I think you're mixing your variable names (active===myClass?).  But won't this approach give a false positive for `class="nothatClassIsnt"`?