# How do you find out if an HTML element has a certain class with plain Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, class

Say I have this html element

```
<div id="hello" class="hello option john">Hello</div>
<div id="hello" class="hello john">Hello</div>
```

. Now I select the element with javascript by it's Id. How would I do an equivalent of `if($('hello').hasClass('option')){//do stuff}`(jQuery) except in plain Javascript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085567/hasclass-with-javascript-or-site-with-jquery-to-javascript-translation

Comment: See - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085567/hasclass-with-javascript-or-site-with-jquery-to-javascript-translation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test if an element contains a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898656/test-if-an-element-contains-a-class)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
if(document.getElementById("hello").className.split(" ").indexOf("option") > -1);
```

That'll do it.

### EDIT: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HRVCV/1/)

or as a prototyped function:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.hasClass = function(c){
    return this.className.split(" ").indexOf(c) > -1
}
```

and

```
document.getElementById("hello").hasClass("option")
```

## Update 2015:

In modern browsers including IE 10 you can write:

```
document.getElementById("hello").classList.contains("option")
```

See the reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

It's supported in all major browsers (ref: http://caniuse.com/#search=classlist)

Comment: Since this question has been visited more than a thousand times so far, can you please update it to cover the native `el.classList.contains(className);` solution as is suggested by http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/?

Comment: @AlexStack  Thanks, but this is still a viable solution and is javascript only.  I'd rather not replace it with a less supported method (classList is IE 10+).  However you are free to post another answer as an alternative solution or edit this answer by adding it as an alternative approach (not sure which is more preferable in the context of stackoverflow's format).  You should have sufficient status to edit.  I believe that privilege is unlocked at 2K rep.

Answer (score 0):

If your targets are modern browsers, you can use [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelector).
Otherwise, you can play with **className** property. ;)

Comment: Actually with a modern browser you would use `.classList`

Answer (score 0):

Is somehow simple:

```
var elHasClass = function(element, classToTest) {
    var pattern = new RegExp("(^| )" + classToTest + "( |$)");
    return pattern.test(element.className) ? true : false;
};
```

Now you can do:

```
if( elHasClass(myEl, 'someCssClass') ) { ... do you stuff here ... }
```