# If element with ID has as class

Tags: javascript, if-statement

What I have now is

```
function setMenuCurrentTo(variable)
{
document.getElementById("game_" + variable).style.display = "block";
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("current_nav");

for (var i=elems.length; i--;) {
elems[i].style.display = "none";
elems[i].className = 'none';
}
document.getElementById("game_" + variable).className="current_nav";
}
}
```

So when I click a tag with a specific element(variable) it adds a content and "hides" another one. But there is a bug that when I click twice in the same button, the content dissapears and I don't have anymore content.

So I tried this code:

```
function setMenuCurrentTo(variable)
{
document.getElementById("game_" + variable).style.display = "block";
if (getElementById("game_" + variable).hasClass("current_nav")) {
}
else {
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("current_nav");

for (var i=elems.length; i--;) {
elems[i].style.display = "none";
elems[i].className = 'none';
}
document.getElementById("game_" + variable).className="current_nav";
}
```

The

```
if (getElementById("game_" + variable).hasClass("current_nav")) {} else {
```

Make the code don't work, the content appears but no other "hides". What is the problem in my code? Thank you, I'm very new at JavaScript, I got yesterday help for the original code. Thank you again.

**EDIT:**

I got the correct answer: from wroniasty

```
function setMenuCurrentTo(variable)
{
document.getElementById("game_" + variable).style.display = "block";
if (jQuery('#game_' + variable).hasClass('current_nav')) {
}
else {
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("current_nav");

for (var i=elems.length; i--;) {
elems[i].style.display = "none";
elems[i].className = 'none';
}
document.getElementById("game_" + variable).className="current_nav";
}
}
```

Comment: could you explain what is this code supposed to do?

Comment: @Muhammad Ramahy It's to make a content appear and other dissapear, like the type of http://otservlist.org/ots/1368480 Where it says description, MOTD, that type of thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getElementById` returns a DOMNode and there is no `hasClass` method in `DOMNode`.

You may want to use a library, like jQuery:

```
jQuery('#game_' + variable).hasClass('current_nav')
```

Comment: or `if (getElementById("game_" + variable).className=="current_nav")`

Comment: @MuhammadRamahy that'll only work if `current_nav` is the only class on the element

Comment: Oops I've assumed so definatly buggy

Comment: Unless IE7 is in play (I think IE8 supports this), you can do `if(... .classList.contains("current_nav"))`

Comment: @JanDvorak: MDN says only IE 10 and above.

Comment: jQuery is kinda overkill for checking if an element has a class. A very, very convenient overkill.

Comment: @Blender ouch. What about regexes? `if(... .className.matches(/(^| )current_nav( |$))/))`... yeah, jQuery makes sense here.

Comment: @JanDvorak: I was thinking more like `.className.split(/\s+/).indexOf('foo')`, but jQuery's always nice

Comment: of course it's trivial to roll your own `hasClass` function, but not only jQuery, but most js client-side libs have one.

Comment: @Blender yep. jQuery _is_ nice. But it's nice to not get lost without it, too :-)

Comment: Correct answer is this one! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 9):

There is no `hasClass` method on native DOM objects. You can either use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList):

```
elem.classList.add('foo')
elem.classList.contains('foo')
```

Or split up `className`:

```
elem.className.split(/\s+/).indexOf('foo') !== -1
```

`classList` isn't supported in IE 9 and lower, but you can get a shim if you really need it. Splitting up `className` with a regex will work just fine without one.

Also, I would consider trying out jQuery. You could simplify your code:

```
function setMenuCurrentTo(name) {
    $('.current_nav').hide();
    $('#game_' + name).show().addClass('current_nav');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`hasClass` is a jQuery function and won't work in plain Javascript. You need to match against the element's `className` attribute instead:

Replace that line with:

```
if (getElementById("game_" + variable).className.match(/\bcurrent_nav\b/)) {} else {
```

This will match the element even if it contains multiple class names.

See ["hasClass" with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085567/hasclass-with-javascript-or-site-with-jquery-to-javascript-translation) for more details.

Comment: `\bfoo\b` matches `foo-bar`

Comment: This one didn't work for me :S

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`.classList` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList) of a DOM Element.

```
getElementById("game_" + variable).classList.contains("current_nav")
```

Patches are available for older browsers *(though usually not IE6/7 if you want it on the prototype)*.

Comment: Didn't work for me :S But thank you :D

Comment: @LohnClaidon: Well... that doesn't make sense unless you're using an old browser.