# protractor check if element is valid

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am wondering if there is a simpler way to check if an input field is valid using protractor. I wrote a helper function which looks like this:

```
isValid(css:string) {
    var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();

    expect(element(by.css(css)).isPresent()).toBe(true);

    element(by.css(css)).getAttribute('class').then(function (attributes) {
        var matches:string[] = attributes.match('ng-invalid');

        deferred.fulfill(matches === null || matches.length === 0);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

That works great but it seems not to be the way you use protractor. It seems to be to complicated...

Do any one of you have a simpler way? Something like

```
expect(element(by.css(css)).isValid()).toBeTruthy
```

Comment: Whats wrong with just `expect(hasClass(element(by.name('your-element')), 'ng-invalid')).toBe(true);`? Maybe check for `ng-dirty` too.

Answer (score 3):

If your angular code has logic for form validation and properly updates `ng-valid`/`ng-invalid`, then you can just do

```
expect(hasClass(element(by.name('your-element')), 'ng-invalid')).toBe(true);
expect(hasClass(element(by.name('your-element')), 'ng-dirty')).toBe(true);
```

And if you want pass `your-element` as a parameter.

Comment: Oh, wait... one more thing... I use Typescript to write my tests and it seems that it does not know where to find hasClass... Do you know from which library that was? It is not in the Protractor Api doku nor in the one from Jasmine...

Comment: @waXve you can read about the hasClass method here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085567/hasclass-with-javascript-or-site-with-jquery-to-javascript-translation