# Find a specific class in an element with many ones

Tags: javascript

How can I select one particular class in an element with many ones ? Here's my problem :

```
<div class="oneclass secondclass theclass otherclass"></div>
```

And in my javascript :

```
var theclass = this.className; // This part must be changed
var otherclass = this.className; // This one too
if (otherclass == "value" ) {
for (n = 1 ; n < mytab.length ; n ++) { if (mytab[n].name == theclass) { ... } }
}
```

I have an onclick function that needs to compare the classes myclass and minorclass, the two others aren't important.
One more thing, because I need to compare the classes, I don't know the name of minorclass and theclass (and oneclass may not be the same, too)

Comment: `if(elm.classList.contains("theclass"))elm.classList.add("differentclass") `

Comment: possible duplicate of ["hasClass" with javascript? or site with jquery to javascript translation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085567/hasclass-with-javascript-or-site-with-jquery-to-javascript-translation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the classList property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) for this.  It's array-like, but has a method called 'contains' which does exactly what you expect (and what you need).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('.theclass');

elem.classList.contains('otherclass') ? elem.classList.remove('otherclass') : elem.classList.add('otherclass');
```

```html
<div class="oneclass secondclass theclass otherclass"></div>
```