# HTML dropdown not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dropdown menu that does not work properly. When i click one of the buttons, a dropdown menu will appear. But when i click the button again it should close, but it dosn't. I know it has something to do with closeAll function, but i still need that function to close another dropdown menu when the first one is already open.

```js
 /* When the user clicks on the button, 
    toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
    function myFunction() {
    closeAll();
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
       }

       function myFunction2() {
        closeAll();
        document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show"); 
    }

    function closeAll(){
     var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
     var i;
     for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
       openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
     }
    }

    // Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
  
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

```css
/* Dropdown Button */
    .dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    /* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
    .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
        background-color: #3e8e41;
    }

    /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
    .dropdown {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 150px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }

    /* Links inside the dropdown */
    .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }

    /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
    #myDropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

    /* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content 
    container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
    .show {display:block;}

    #myDropdown2{
     min-width:200px;
     border:4px solid red;
 
    }

    #myDropdown2 a:hover{
     color:red;
    }

    .left-bar{
     float:left;
    }

    .right-bar{
     float:left;
    }
```

```html
    

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
      <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button onclick="myFunction2()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
      <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
     <div class="left-bar">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
     </div>
 
     <div class="right-bar">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
     </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> your Functions (`myFunction() and myFunction2()`) first close all dropdown menu using `closeAll();` and next line `document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");` shows it again.So,when you click the button againو It does not close.
>
> **For Fix it :**
>
> Just remove Function `closeAll();` and change your code Like this :

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.remove("show");
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function myFunction2() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.remove("show");
    document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

**Full code :**

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.remove("show");
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.remove("show");
  document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');

      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

#myDropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}


/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content 
    container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */

.show {
  display: block;
}

#myDropdown2 {
  min-width: 200px;
  border: 4px solid red;
}

#myDropdown2 a:hover {
  color: red;
}

.left-bar {
  float: left;
}

.right-bar {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction2()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
    <div class="left-bar">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>

    <div class="right-bar">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now both menus stay open when you click on both buttons.

Comment: @Barmar , Thank you i Updated it.

Answer (score -1):

Remove this Function for `myFunction()` & `myFunction2()`  `closeAll();`

you already use `ToggleClass`

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
    toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function myFunction2() {
  
  document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show");
}

function closeAll() {
  var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
    var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
  }
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');

      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

#myDropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}


/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content 
    container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */

.show {
  display: block;
}

#myDropdown2 {
  min-width: 200px;
  border: 4px solid red;
}

#myDropdown2 a:hover {
  color: red;
}

.left-bar {
  float: left;
}

.right-bar {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction2()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
    <div class="left-bar">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>

    <div class="right-bar">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now clicking on one button doesn't close the other.

Answer (score -1):

In the first step you close all dropdowns and after that toggle the current one which then will be reopened. If you want to change this behaviour you have to change the closeAll() function to receive one parameter which would be the current dropdown or button and only close all but this one.

```
closeAll(currentDropdown){
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if(openDropdown != currentDropdown){
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
        }
    }
}
```

You could save the states the elements should have in an array and apply all these every time one is clicked.

```
// executed once on page load
var dropdowns = new array();
var tmpdropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < tmpdropdowns.length; i++) {
    dropdowns[tmpdropdowns[i].id] = 0;
}


// executed on click of one button
for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
    dropdowns[i] = 0;
}
dropdowns[/*clicked id*/] = (dropdowns[/*clicked id*/] + 1) % 2;
for (var key in dropdowns) {
   if(dropdowns[key] == 0) {
       document.getElementById[key].classList.remove("show");
   } else {
       document.getElementById[key].classList.add("show");
   }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind telling me why you downvoted? I answered because I want to help you and if this answer didn't help or wasn't detailed enough or whatever I can improve it if you tell me what is missing or wrong.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that after you call `closeAll()`, you then toggle the dropdown that the user clicked on, which opens that one again.

You need to test whether the current one is already open, and not re-open it.

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
    toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  var isOpen = document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.contains("show");
  closeAll();
  if (!isOpen) {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.add("show");
  }
}

function myFunction2() {
  var isOpen = document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.contains("show");
  closeAll();
  if (!isOpen) {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show");
  }
}

function closeAll() {
  var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
    var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
  }
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');

      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

#myDropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}


/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content 
    container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */

.show {
  display: block;
}

#myDropdown2 {
  min-width: 200px;
  border: 4px solid red;
}

#myDropdown2 a:hover {
  color: red;
}

.left-bar {
  float: left;
}

.right-bar {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction2()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
    <div class="left-bar">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>

    <div class="right-bar">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this:** remove the class`show`of another dropdown when hasClass of `show` element clicked dropdown .because each time of you click `closeAll` was remove the `show` in all dropdown .So you could validate only remove the hasClass  of`show` element .It prevent the toggle event of `dropdown` also

[`Array.prototype.indexOf.call(document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList, 'show')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085567/hasclass-with-javascript)

Its used to find the `hasClass`

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
    toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
if(Array.prototype.indexOf.call(document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList, 'show')){
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
   document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.remove("show");
  }
  else{
  closeAll();
  }
  
}

function myFunction2() {if(Array.prototype.indexOf.call(document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList, 'show')){
  document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show");
     document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.remove("show");
  }
  else{
  closeAll()
  }
  
}

function closeAll() {
  var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
    var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
  }
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');

      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

#myDropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}


/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content 
    container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */

.show {
  display: block;
}

#myDropdown2 {
  min-width: 200px;
  border: 4px solid red;
}

#myDropdown2 a:hover {
  color: red;
}

.left-bar {
  float: left;
}

.right-bar {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction2()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
    <div class="left-bar">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>

    <div class="right-bar">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @downvoters .please clarify what wrong with my answer