# check if my body tag has a class, in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to simply show/hide content; by creating an `if statement` in plain JS to  detect if the current body `tag` has a specific class attached; *i.e.* home

I am trying the below; on the correct page, but am not getting the alert.

```
var elem = document.querySelector('body');

if (elem.classList.contains('test')) {
    alert('test');
}
```

***no jQuery!!***

error with the above code is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
```

I just want this to run on page load

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Make sure you are running this method after the DOM content has loaded

Comment: So are you getting an error? When is the code run? Code looks like it should work so it has to be something else.

Comment: Are you sure the `<body>` element has the class `body`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the "hasClass" function with plain JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085567/what-is-the-hasclass-function-with-plain-javascript)

Comment: Btw, use `document.body`.

Comment: document.body('body')?

Comment: Please, can you share where is placed that code in your HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you wait for the DOMContentLoaded event you should be golden.
Check out the tests below.

NOTE: Snippet engine is NOT a good test for this, the HTML is always ready :)

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  console.log(document.body.classList);
  console.log(document.body.className);
  if(document.body.classList.length > 0) {
    console.log(document.body.className);
  }

});
```

```html
<body class="testing test2">

<p>Hello world</p>

</body>
```