# Spacebar (keycode 32) to act as Enter key except inside an input field

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, accessibility, keycode

I'm working on adding accessibility to a program for hard-of-seeing users. For this, we are using the tab key to maneuver through the page. The user can then use the spacebar as the enter key, to open a link they are focused on, for example. I'm working on the spacebar to act in this manner at all times (using "e.preventDefault()"), except of course when inside an input field. I've written what makes logical sense to me, but does not work. Does anyone have any suggestions, please? This is what I have in a javascript file:

```
var textFieldEntry = document.querySelectorAll('input.field-input');
if (e.key == 'Space' || e.keyCode == 32) {
  if (e.target !== textFieldEntry) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.click();
  };
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? semantic HTML will function as expected so use `<a>` for links `<button>` for buttons etc. For a hyperlink to be valid it must have a valid `href`, is this the problem you are trying to overcome?

Comment: p.s. it is `Enter` for hyperlinks, `space` is for checkboxes etc. are you just getting confused as to how each item should behave?

Comment: I'm doing this for a client who requested their site to act in this manner. I'm now researching if there's a "preventDefault() unless" type of coding.

Comment: changing expected behaviour is a terrible idea for accessibility as a user may press `space` to scroll the page, having it activate links unexpectedly would actually make the site **less** accessible.

Comment: btw the reason you have an issue with your code is that `e.target` is a single item, `querySelectorAll` grabs all items so they do not match, look at implementing a ".hasClass" function and check the classname instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085567/what-is-the-hasclass-function-with-plain-javascript

Comment: I put your code below with some logs to show you why it doesn't work, look at the contents of `e.target` in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**not an answer, designed to show OP why his function doesn't work as intended and will be removed**

```js
var textFieldEntry = document.querySelectorAll('input.field-input');
$(document).on('keydown', function(e){
if (e.key == 'Space' || e.keyCode == 32) {
  console.log("space pressed");
  console.log("e.target", e.target);
  console.log("textFieldEntry", textFieldEntry);
  if (e.target !== textFieldEntry) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.click();
  };
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="field-input"/>
<input class="field-input"/>
<input class="field-input"/>
```

Comment: Made this a community Wiki so people can fiddle with it, will delete it once OP responds

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you!

Comment: oh I cant delete it now you accepted :-P oh well, glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Please correct me this text,
I am using android browser
so i need the spacebar to act as physical spacebar
with an API, This physical spacebar is actually itself acting as Enter (to select from list)  and adding "space" to the text.
its like an interactive text correction

```js
var textFieldEntry = document.querySelectorAll('textarea.field-input');
$(document).on('keyup', function(e){
if (e.key == 'Space' || e.keyup == 229) {
  console.log("space pressed");
  console.log("e.target", e.target);
  console.log("textFieldEntry", textFieldEntry);
  if (e.target !== textFieldEntry) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.click();
  };
}
});
```