# How check if a particular element has a certain class?

Tags: jquery

Does jquery have a boolean function to determine if a particular element has a certain class?

Comment: Type the exact text of your question into Google and the first result is your question, the second result is the `.hasClass()` function within the jQuery API reference. Also this is a duplicate of [Determine if an element has a CSS class with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263232/determine-if-an-element-has-a-css-class-with-jquery)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$(selector).hasClass('whatclass')
```

Answer (score 2):

http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Here you will get all the information you need along with samples.