# How check if body has a specific class with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

How can I check if body has specific class?
This is my case:

```
<body class="foo foo1 foo3"></body>
```

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript). It has some great examples.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test if an element contains a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898656/test-if-an-element-contains-a-class) -- please use the search before you ask a new question. How it is been done with jQuery [has been ask before as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263232/determine-if-an-element-has-a-css-class-with-jquery).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
function hasClass(ele,cls) {
     return ele.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)'));
}

if(hasClass(document.getElementById("test"), "test")){//do something};
```

maybe this helps you :-)

With the use of jQuery it would be easier and less code but nevermind !

Comment: You should add the simple or double quotes otherwise it doesn’t work : `$('body')`

Answer (score 88):

There's now a super-easy way to do this:

```
document.body.classList.contains('my-class-name')
```

Answer (score 14):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].className.match(/foo/)
```

Comment: This solution also matches classes that contain foo, like "foobar".

Comment: I am getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined`

Answer (score 10):

[jQuery.hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) works for me...

non jQuery answer, try `if( document.body.className.match('foo') ) { ... }`

Comment: I think this should have been the answer; no need for an additional function; much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Mozilla classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.classList) for this.

The linked page also has a cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 1):

This returns a string of `true or false` when looking for a specific body class using jQuery's `.hasClass`:

```
if ($("body").hasClass("modal-open")) {
                        $("body").removeClass("modal-open");
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This returns a string of `true` or `false` when looking for a specific body class using jQuery's `.hasClass`:

```
$("body").hasClass("your-class-name").toString();
```