# How do I hide a opt-in script from logged in users?

Tags: javascript

I run a membership site and have a script that shows an opt-in pop up form after visitors are on the page for more than 10 seconds. However, this pop-up shows up for public uses as well as our paid members.

How can I wrap the pop-up `<script>` in some custom JavaScript code to detect the presence of the "logged-in" body class? If it is found, the script should not fire.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How check if body has a specific class with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532639/how-check-if-body-has-a-specific-class-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (document.querySelectorAll('.logged-in').length) {
    // do your worst (here)
}
```

You can use `querySelectorAll` function to search for that DOM object on your page. and if it exists then run your code.

---

Might be better though to just have the backend handle this part and only load the js for your logged in users when your user is **actually** logged in

Comment: Thanks Truvia, but I would actually need the exact opposite of this. If the .logged-in DOM exists, then DONT run the code. How would I do this?

Comment: Logical Not operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT

Comment: Why this works: if statement checks against falsey so .length being anything greater than 0 is truthy. So checking .length for elements will pass the condition, if no element exist it fails it. Adding in the NOT converts the 0 to true (not falsey) and the positive numbers to false (not truthy). I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @Tuvia Here is the script that I am trying to run for if the logged-in DOM is not present: <script data-leadbox="145ef7173f72a2:10453ce71346dc" data-url="https://weisse.leadpages.co/leadbox/145ef7173f72a2%3A10453ce71346dc/5657582312095744/" data-config="%7B%22type%22%3A%22time%22%2C%22settings%22%3A%7B%22seconds%22%3A15%2C%22days%22%3A0%2C%22views%22%3A0%7D%7D" type="text/javascript" src="https://weisse.leadpages.co/leadbox-1011.js"></script>   How do I add the code solution you mentioned above? Unfortunatly I do not have access to the .jc file as it is hosted by LeadPages

Comment: @GlennMc handle that server side (since that is the side that should know if you are logged in or not.

Comment: @Tuvia Unfortunately I'm using a platform that doesn't give me access to server side scripts. I can only add scripting viea the <script></script> tags. How can I accomplish this using that method?