# How to put the flag status in the image tag

Tags: php, javascript, css, image

I need to check the status of the image in the img tag by using flag like imagestatus =1 in the following code

```
 echo '<a href="#" class="swap-menu"><img id="menu_image"  src="images/collapsed.gif" hspace = "2"/>'.$B->getAttribute('TITLE').'</a>';
```

here's the js file

```
$('.swap-menu').bind('click', function (event) {
    $('.sub-menu').find("+ ul").slideUp(1);
    $(this).find("+ ul").slideToggle("fast");
    $(this).find("img").attr('src', 'images/expanded.gif');
});
```

Comment: seeing your code in js file seems that you are using jQuery. so to update the `src` of `img` tag you can use jQuery toggle function. http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 1):

I would add a class to the image when you are replacing the images src.

I'm assuming you are using jQuery, from your code.

See http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Then you can use the hasClass method. See [Determine if an element has a CSS class with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263232/determine-if-an-element-has-a-css-class-with-jquery)