# Check if div has exactly the classes in my list

Tags: jquery

I'm searching a way to check if a div has **exactly** the classes in my list. Example:

My list of classes: .cat, .dog **and** .fish

If the div .animals has **only** divs with these classes, do something, but if there's another class  wich is not included in my list (i.e.: .cat, .dog, .fish **and** .house) or if a class is missing (i.e.: .cat **and** .dog) do something different.

There's a way to do this? I tried to check with .has(), .hasclass() and .is(), but I couldn't make it work as I want.

Comment: Please post what you have tried. Your question is not clear to me. Do you want to check whether an element has all the three classes itself or whether an element has other elements with those classes inside of it?

Comment: Do you have a list of all possible classnames?

Comment: @FelixKling only the things I said, like: ($('.animals').is(".fish, .cat, .dog"))
using .has(), .hasclass() and .is() and things like these.

Comment: @YotamOmer at the top of the post I said on "My list of classes: .cat, .dog and .fish". But if you asking for the classes wich I want to don't be included, no. I'm trying to do a "item mixer" for an browser game... and I want to make a button be displayed if the correct classes was apendded to the "mixer" div, so will be lots of itens, wich one with its class.

Comment: But don't you have a more "complete" approach? `$('.animals').is(".fish, .cat, .dog"))` by itself doesn't do anything. And it's still unclear (to me) what *exactly* you are trying to do.

Comment: I would probably have used datasets instead of classes here, btw. This simplifies a logic - and shows your true intent better, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $el = $('.animals');
// using .is makes sure it doesn't matter the order
if ( $el.is('.cat.dog.fish') ) {
    if ( $.trim($el.attr('class').replace(/\b(animals|cat|dog|fish)\b/g, '')) ) {
        // it has some other class
        return;
    }
    // You're good to go
} else {
    // does not have all classes
}
```

Added boundaries and global flag to the regex.

Based on the fiddle in the OP's comments:

```
var $el = $('.animals');
var children = $el.children();
if ( children.filter(":not(.dog):not(.cat):not(.fish)" ).length ) {
    // Something else is in there
    alert("There's something else!");
} else {
    if ( ! children.filter('.dog').length || ! children.filter('.cat').length || ! children.filter('.fish').length ) {
        // Something is missing
        alert("You're missing something");
        return;
    }
    // Good to go.
    alert("Everything is good!");
}
```

Though, I'm pretty sure there is a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: @raina77ow good point. I've updated the regex to reflect that and added the global flag

Comment: Didn't worked for me. http://jsfiddle.net/GfYCW/

Comment: Updated with new approach. Your original question made it sound like your structure was more like `<div class="animals dog cat fish"></div>`, which seems to be how everyone took it.

Comment: Oh, man. Thank you a lot. I really think I'm trying to do this at the wrong way... but you helped me a lot with your code.

Comment: @Jimmy: If you read [my very first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644356/check-if-div-has-exactly-the-classes-in-my-list/17644405#comment25693499_17644356) on your question, you will notice that I already asked for clarification of your problem. If you would have edited your question to include the HTML code (and provided a better explanation), you would have gotten more relevant answers from the start. Next time please provide clarification if someone asks for it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use hasClass();

like so...

```
 var check = $('.animals').hasClass('fish cat dog');
 if(check) {
 //do stuff you wanna do   
 } else {
 //do other stuff
 }
```

However, this will check if it has those classes in that order, if you wanna check if it has one of the classes. then do...

```
var dog = $('.animals').hasClass('dog');
var cat = $('.animals').hasClass('cat');
var fish = $('.animals').hasClass('fish');
```

Then you can do an if for those variables that you need.

```
if((dog)&&(cat)&&(fish)){
 //do stuff
 } else {
 //do other stuff
 }
```

etc...

Comment: The documentation doesn't mention that `.hasClass` accepts a space separated list of classes. Does this really work? And does it return `true` if the element has all of these classes or just one of them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263232/determine-if-an-element-has-a-css-class-with-jquery

Comment: I think in the example above it will return true, only if they are all three, in that order, that is why I provided the other way as well...

Comment: So, it doesn't really "work" ;)

Comment: So, as @FelixKling, it doesn't work.