# Javascript to check if div has child with that classname

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So,

How to check with JavaScript if DIV has that classname? Here's an example HTML
`<div class="cart"></div>` that would be the parent and then JavaScript creates under that div's upon a click, but if it's already there and you click the item then it's just going to remove it. Example: Button is yellow and if you click it, it add's item to the cart and changes button class to selected. If you click it again, it will remove selected class and also remove item from the cart. I do have a code for the clicking part and adding it to cart, but not for removing it.. How could I do it?

JavaScript

```
    $(".item-card").mousedown(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("selected-item");
        var itemnume = $(this).find("img").attr("title");
        $("#itemcart").append($("<div id="+itemnume+">"+itemnume+"</div>"));
    });
```

Here it adds the item to the cart, but if you would reclick it, it will do it again. I've tried write a function, which checks that is the item already in cart, if it is then remove it, if not then add it, but I never succeed. I think that would solve my problem though.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: I will edit my first post :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine if an element has a CSS class with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263232/determine-if-an-element-has-a-css-class-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

```
   $(".item-card").click(function() {
  var itemnume = $(this).find("img").attr("title");
  var replaced = itemnume.split(' ').join('_');

  if ($(this).hasClass('selected-item')) {
    console.log()
    $("#" + replaced).remove();
  } else {
    $("#itemcart").append($("<div id=" + replaced + ">" + itemnume + "</div>"));
  }
  $(this).toggleClass("selected-item");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0tusd19b/

Comment: Thank You! Sadly it didn't work out though. :( It doesn't want to remove div id called by that name. Here's how it looks after he created it `<div id="The+Best+Ball">The Best Ball</div>`

Comment: it works you have invalid ids that is why is not working for you

Comment: If I click it, then it goes selected item, but it doesn't add item right away. if I click again then it adds it.

Comment: How I got invalid ids?

Comment: I edited a bit that part, I added that spaces replaced with +, because it wouldn't work at all then :/

Comment: how did you added +?

Comment: `var replaced = itemnume.split(' ').join('+');`

Comment: Chrome console: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #The+Best+Ball

Comment: that is a invalid id

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: It adds to cart, but can't remove because of syntax error.  #The_Best_Ball

Comment: are you using strict mode?

Comment: It would remove it, but it can't find the #itemname. It can be because, it is not searching it under the #itemname, it is searching it under item-selected?

Comment: i tested the code in the jsfiddle attached and it works

Comment: Hmm, I think I got a different code a bit lol. Okay so..

Comment: Items are shown as "item-cards". (JavaScript creates card for each item), but if I look the code then you search it from there (if item is there, then remove it), but it should search it from #itemcart or am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: ids should be unique .the syntax i am using will search in all the dom for that element

Comment: hmm I dont get it why it doesnt work lol :D

Comment: Doesn't make any sense :/

Comment: as you can see my jsfiddle is working, you may have other errors in your page

Comment: Nope, I don't see any other. Error log doesn't show any, you don't know any other reason why it couldn't find it?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ax0351 maybe it helps, I think it is 100% my fault I didn't said it earlier maybe if it matters :D

Comment: javascipt doesn't have error logs it has console errors,your prtscr doesn't help

Comment: Thought it will, but okay. hmm, I don't get it then how it can't fint it :D

Comment: Took code from my prntscr added it to the jsfiddle, works there but not on mine.. what the hell..

Comment: what can't you find?

Comment: from a scale from 1 to 10 how good are you with javascript?

Comment: not best lol like you can see.. can't even solve that easy problem..

Comment: Hmm, I got some items with (), and it then works. I will do script to remove (), but still it doesn't remove items though. Choosed item without (). Added it there clicked again, didn't "removed" it :/

Comment: Alright, found out that if you use append, then to remove it you have to use somekind of .on function. Have to see though how to use it, that's why remove doesn't work.

Comment: this code should work provided the ids are valid and unique

Comment: idk, if I readed it right then have to use somehow that  part. I got it working, but it was removing wrong thing lol.. Have to put it to right place

Comment: good to know, please accept the answer if it's the right one

Comment: I'll try to get it working, then I'll accept your answer :).

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle with your error?

Comment: Not getting any error atm, trying to figure out where I should bind click event so if you click again it will remove.

Comment: the code above does that

Comment: Idk, it wont remove the div for me on site

Comment: do you have console erors when you click to remove it?

Comment: I am complete retarded. I think I should learn how to copy paste lol